# Real Analysis: Series and Converges of sequences

Tags: real-analysis

a) For all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $a\neq0$, show that
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{a-1}{a^k}=1-\frac{1}{a^n}$$
b) For a sequence $(x_n)$ in $\mathbb{R}$, suppose that there exists an $b\in(0,1)$ such that
$$|x_{n+1}-x_n|\leq b^n,\text{ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$}$$
Use part (a) to prove that $x_n\to x$ for some $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Note: if $0<b<1$ then $b=\frac{1}{a}$ for some $a>1$. Then use part (a), since $a>1\neq 0$

My Concern: I already proved the part (a). In part (b), I don't know how to prove it. Does anyone can prove and explain the part (b)?

Comment: b) is  a very popular question on this site and it has been answered  many times.

Comment: Wow really?!
I will try to search it and study their solution Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have for $n>m$,

$$\begin{align}
|x_{n}-x_m|&=|x_{n}-x_{n-1}+x_{n-1}-x_{n-2}+\cdots +x_{m+1}-x_m|\\\\
&=\left|\sum_{k=m+1}^{n}(x_{k}-x_{k-1})\right|\\\\
&\le \sum_{k=m}^{n-1} b^{k}\\\\
&=\frac{b^{m}-b^{n}}{1-b}
\end{align}$$

Since $b<1$, then we have that for all $\varepsilon>0$, $|x_n-x_m|<\varepsilon$ whenever $m$ and $n$ are sufficiently large.  Inasmuch as $x_n$ is a Cauchy sequence, it converges.  And we are done!

Comment: I really understand your solution, thank your for this!!

Comment: Pleased to hear.  You're welcome.